# Equivalent of SBT's "provided" dependency for fatjar in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Using Scala's SBT, I can indicate that a dependency required for compilation will be "provided" in the runtime environment like so:

```
val catalina = "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-catalina" % V.tomcat % "provided"
```

A dependency marked as provided in this way will automatically be ignored when building a fatjar using sbt-assembly.

What is the equivalent functionality for Gradle?

Comment: Googling for "gradle provided" directly leads to http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_best_define_dependencies_as_provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Gradle does not add a `provided` configuration out-of-the-box. However, there are a couple of plugins that add this functionality:

- [Nebula extra configurations plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin)
- [Gradle propdep plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin)

Alternatively, you can also model this configuration yourself. You will find many examples for this on the [Gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle).