# Provided dependency from project (Gradle)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can we declare a dependency as provided from another module?  i.e. something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
    provided 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}
```

but instead of pulling dependency from a repo, I want to include a project in another project.  I would expect something like this to work:

```
dependency {
    compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
    provided project(':mymodule')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Gradle does not have a built in `provided` scope/configuration. You can define your own provided configuration. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899917/745574

But in your case, you do not really need it. As long as mymodule is already in settings.gradle, just include your module as:

```
compile project(':mymodule')
```