# Remove dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

In my project I have to libraries that uses `com.google.javascript:closure-compiler`. Due to some jars problem I want to exclude one. To do this I wrote this code:

```
compile('com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.8.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.javascript', module: 'closure-compiler'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew dependecies` old jar seems to be removed.

My problem occurs when I run `./gradlew install` and import my lib in another project, because in another project I have both jars. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `provided` configuration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899917/449652).

Once that is in place, try changing your code to something like:

```
provided('com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.8.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.javascript', module: 'closure-compiler'
}
```